# Removing alsa module from kernel saying module is in use

Tags: alsa

I am working on ALSA driver development on the FPGA Board.
I am able to insert the alsa module and do PCM transfer but when I am trying to remove that module it is showing module is in use.

ik have preallocated pages by snd_pcm_preallocate_pages_for_all() for PCM of continuous type. and in hw params i am allocating memory by using snd_pcm_lib_malloc_pages();

so every time when I am trying to remove my module it says module is in use by snd_pcm and some other alsa snd's.

Can anyone tell how to resolve this issue?

Thanks and Best Regards.

Comment: See [How can I find out what programs are using sound in Linux?](https://superuser.com/q/47146/157027)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply,         but i am facing some different issue i know what are the driver using alsa  stuff .  And i have blacklist all the other device as well ! Now my driver is using snd_pcm for doing the pcm transfer and when i am trying to release my driver it is saying cant remove your module bcj module is in used by snd_pcm and when i am trying to release snd_pcm it is saying your driver is using so cant release .....   so  i just want to know if i want to remove my module how i can do it !!!!!!!!   Thanks and Best Regards.

Comment: This might be a bug in your driver.

Comment: And what could be the possible bug can I know ?

Comment: It could be anything. Hard to say without seeing the source.

Comment: Anyway, the `fuser`/`lsof` commands show which *programs* are accessing the device. Are there any?

Comment: i have check the following dummy driver         i) https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/sound/drivers/aloop.c                     ii)  https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/sound/drivers/dummy.c          these driver are also having the same issue after inserting if i try to do rmmod i am getting the same as i am getting for my driver message "module is in use" !!!!!!!     can you check and let me know what is the problem with these modules  ..... so if i  will be able to remove these dummy driver i can remove my driver as well         Thanks and Best Regards, Devendra yadav

Comment: ya my module is in used by i) snd_pcm ii) snd_timer iii) snd   ......... so i tried to release snd_pcm so it says it is in used by snd_timer, snd and my_module ,,  and vice versa i was not able to release anyone of them because they are dependent to each other ......       anything else i can try with |||||||  Thanks and Best Regards,   Devendra Yadav

Comment: And one more thing : => i have kept timer() in timer as start_timer and stop_timer in the trigger() , with that i am able to get audio in vlc player but if i remove timer()s there will be no audio..        i really don't know why ? does timer have any thing to do with dma_transfer ... if i kept timer() and try to work on interrupt based mechanism will it work  ?     kindly let me know ,,, Thanks and Best Regards,