# How to force remove alsa module

Tags: alsa, external-soundcard

Currently I am facing an issue as after loading my alsa_module I am unable to release it. Is there any way to force remove it from the kernel?

I have tried:

1. `rmmod -f alsa_module`
2. `modprobe -r alsa_module` (even with `-f` option)

Related questions:

- [ALSA card registration and release](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1002114/alsa-card-registration-and-release)
- [Removing alsa module from kernel saying module is in use](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1042565/removing-alsa-module-from-kernel-saying-module-is-in-use)

Comment: Is it really called `alsa_module`? Did you write it yourself?

Comment: no the name is "my_audio_module" ;    Ya For Reading the Audio data from FPGA Board alsa driver is required(for doing PCM Transfer) ; because Board user won't be having  any driver for reading audio data;   the problem i am getting is while release only, rest of the things are working fine ; i am able to read data data from device but as i said before while releasing it is saying module is in  used by snd_pcm, and snd_timer and same if i try to release snd_pcm or snd_timer modules for "my_audio_module" ; I really don't know how to resolve this issue,    please let me know if you any idea; BR,

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the driver. Without the source code, help is impossible.

Comment: I am unable to put my whole source code(too long)but i am sending memory allocation code :-                                                                                                                                           ret_prealloc = snd_pcm_lib_preallocate_pages_for_all(
            pcm,
            //SNDRV_DMA_TYPE_CONTINUOUS,
            SNDRV_DMA_TYPE_DEV,
            //snd_dma_continuous_data(GFP_KERNEL),
            snd_dma_pci_data(alsa_dev),
            audio_pcm_hardware.buffer_bytes_max,
            audio_pcm_hardware.buffer_bytes_max
            );

Comment: And memory allocation in hw_params :                                                                                     ret =  snd_pcm_lib_malloc_pages(substream, params_buffer_bytes(hw_params));   This function returns positive number like 1 is it correct ?

Comment: or, can you share me your email id so that i can sent you the source cose #CL